# Run Xcode on PowerPC

Tags: xcode

Is there some special tricks to launch Xcode on PowerPC?

I can install it, but it doesn't launch, just hangs.
(Have to use off-button to turn it off)

Comment: Not enough details. What's your Mac? Mac OS X version? Xcode version? E.g. Xcode 3.1.3 runs perfectly fine on my PowerBook 12" @ 1GHz with Mac OS X 10.4.8.

Comment: Im sorry: 10.5.8, 2GHz PowerPC G5, 2Go DDR RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 3.1.3 is the latest release compatible with PowerPC.

Comment: Its the same (as 3.1.4), actually I had Interface Builder opening some weeks ago, so it is perhaps something that has happened to the system in-between.

Comment: Posted new question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716046/problems-with-xcode-3-1-3-on-powerpc