# Problems with XCode 3.1.3 on PowerPC

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have some problems running XCode 3.1.3 I have actually had Interface Builder working (But not now).
I think it is related to having tried to force install of higher versions?  (So I could try to remove or downgrade something).  Or that I cleaned up a bit to much?
From:

/Developer1.3/Applications/Interface Builder.app/Contents/MacOS:

dyld: Symbol not found: __NSConcreteGlobalBlock
  Referenced from: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Answer (score 1):

I have a Power PC G4 tower and I have made the aspen simulator for ios sdk work in xcode 3.0 but the update of the aspen simulator (iPhone simulator in dev tools 3.1) won't work because its intel only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it might be time to replace your computer. With PPC you can't run Snow Leopard, without which you can't develop for SL, making things, well, difficult.

As a point of interest, your problem is probably caused by not having the Snow Leopard system libraries that Xcode requires; because they provide, among other things, blocks.

Comment: What I want is iPhone, and it supposed to be possible.

Comment: Actually, it's possible despite not being supposed to. ;) It's possible that the information on what is possible and not is outdated, I doubt that unless you have a G5 tower developing for the iPhone will work very well, in terms of performance.